# Get everyday of the week in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to write a sql query  for getting the every day of the week.
like if i run SELECT GETDATE() i am getting today'day date if run the getdate()-1 i am getting only column with yesterday date. Instead i want to get the every day in a week in different columns, someone please help with the SQL. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We need to see your effort in order to help solve your issue.

Comment: You will want to use a table variable, a start date variable, and an end date variable. Run a loop for each day between the start date and end date, populating the table variable with the date, then perform a pivot on the table variable to get your results as multiple columns instead of 1.

Comment: This what i tried                                                                                   
 WITH CTE_Calendar([Date])
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20170619' as date) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT   DATEADD(dd, 1, [Date])
  FROM CTE_Calendar
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [Date]) <= '20170626'
)
SELECT [Date], 
       [Day]=Datename(dw, [Date]) 
FROM   CTE_Calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) Monday,
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 1 Tuesday,
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 2 Wednsday,
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 3 Thursday,
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 4 Friday,
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 5 Saturday,
       DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, GETDATE()), 0) + 6 Sunday;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT 
  Day1 = CAST(getdate() AS date),
  Day2 = CAST(getdate()+1 AS date),
  Day3 = CAST(getdate()+2 AS date),
  Day4 = CAST(getdate()+3 AS date),
  Day5 = CAST(getdate()+4 AS date),
  Day6 = CAST(getdate()+5 AS date),
  Day7 = CAST(getdate()+6 AS date);
```

Returns:

```
Day1       Day2       Day3       Day4       Day5       Day6       Day7
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2017-06-26 2017-06-27 2017-06-28 2017-06-29 2017-06-30 2017-07-01 2017-07-02
```

If this is not what you are looking for can you post what you want your query to return?

Comment: Be careful here. If this is using a table and the datatype is datetime2 this will fail. Better to use DATEADD to add dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations